# Possible to overlap featured images?

Tags: image

I'm trying to make the featured images on the front page overlap like this -

[image]

So far I have managed this -

[image]

Some images are landscape and some are portrait. I want all the images to be the same width but not the same height so have applied **height:auto**.

The CSS for the featured images -

```
.home_post_box { 
float: left; 
height: 345px;
width: 345px; 
position: relative; 
display: inline-block;}

.home_post_box img { 
width: 350px; 
height: auto; 
transform:  -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-1deg);  
-webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg); 
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
outline: 1px solid transparent; 
text-align: center; 
left:0px; top:0px; 
z-index:1; 
float: left;}
```

Here is [my site](http://tinyurl.com/kqngj4g).

Thank you, and any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This seems mostly like pure CSS question and might be better asked at [so]. Please try to elaborate which _WordPress_ aspects of it you have trouble achieving if you want to keep it here.

Comment: Rarst, it is the Wordpress featured image that I am trying to work with

Comment: Featured image feature ends at the point where WP outputs it into page source. It's not relevant to how you style it with CSS in this case it seems.

Comment: Rarst, ok I will move this to Stack Overflow. Apologies for being a n00b

Comment: No worries, good luck working it out. :)

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?